# height according to aspect ratio like image in HTML

Tags: html, css

Whenever we render an image its render with set of height and width that can be adjust itself according to parent height and width. We can say it render according to aspect ratio.

The same effect I want to have on `div` or `span`. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q7rwxm6p/3/)

HTML

```
<div class="one">
  <img src="http://img.freepik.com/free-vector/abstract-geometric-pattern_23-2147508597.jpg?size=338&ext=jpg" alt="">
</div>

<div class="one">
  <span></span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.one {width: 200px;}
img {width: 100%; display:block}
span {display:block; background:red; max-width: 100%; height:100%!important; min-height:300px}
```

Comment: You an use % for width and height

Comment: My question is little bit different. Div height and with should work like in manner image does.